# SP Online - Can't add a page image/logo - Says "Sorry, you don't have access to this page"

Tags: sharepoint-online

Receiving this error when trying to add an image.  SP Online, no sub-sites, 2-users, both have "full control" (I believe).

In a couple forums it talks about the issue and says to enable something in SP Admin for custom scripts.  After the change it says it can take up to 24-hours.

Is that the fix?  Seems really weird since it's a new SP Online setup with nothing special.

"Sorry, you don't have access to this page"